# Add parent key to PHP JSON

Tags: php, json

I've been trying to add a parent key "data" to a PHP $dataset json:

my $dataset json:

```
[ 
    { 
    "id":"H",
    "description": "Hello"
    },
    { 
    "id":"B",
    "description":"Bye",
    },
]
```

the final output must be

```
[ 
    "data": {
        { 
            "id":"H",
            "description": "Hello"
        },
        { 
            "id":"B",
            "description":"Bye",
        },
    },
]
```

Can you please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of JSON type is `{key:vale}`
your code should be like:

```
{
    "data": [
        { 
            "id":"H",
            "description": "Hello"
        },
        { 
            "id":"B",
            "description":"Bye",
        },
    ],
}
```

Try this out:

```
$final_result = array('data' => $dataset)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to decode to array and add the parent then encode again to json.

```
$output_json = json_encode(array("data" => json_decode($dataset)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = [
 'data'   => $dataset,
 'status' => true
];

return json_encode($data);
```